# Changing onClick of a span when it is clicked using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, recursion

I've created a program that randomly spawns a span (in the form of a circle). I want to change the onClick of the previous span class when clicked on.

I've already attempted to set the id of the new span element to something that creates recursively (span.id = "a" + t; t++;) or something like that.

```
   <!doctype html>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
  family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="/vNidjVg- 
  _400x400.jpg"/>
  <style>
  body{
     background-color: #010417;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;

  }

  @keyframes a{
     0% {opacity: 0;}
    100%{opacity: 1;}
   }
    button{
       background-color: #010417;
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 4px solid white;
      color: white;
      padding: 10px 26px;
      font-size: 20px;
   }
   </style>
    <div id="myDIV">
    <script>
    document.title = prompt("I don't know what to make the 
    document's title, so what do you want it to be called?");

    function getRndInteger(min, max) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
    }
   var but = 2;
   var x = 0
   function button(){

   if(but === 2){
     myFunction();
     but = 0;

      }else{}

       }
    var t = 0;
    var q = -1;
    function myFunction() {

      var para = document.createElement("SPAN");
      para.style.position = "absolute";
     x = getRndInteger(0, (window.innerWidth - 60))
     para.style.left = x + "px"
     var p = getRndInteger(0, (window.innerHeight - 60))
     para.style.top = p + "px"
     para.style.display = "inline-block;"
     para.style.height = "50px"
     para.style.width = "50px"
     para.style.backgroundColor="red"
     para.style.borderRadius = "50px"
     para.style.border = "1px solid black"
       para.style.animation = "1s a linear"

     para.id = "a" + t;

      document.getElementById("a" + q).onclick=f
     q++
     t++;

     para.onclick=myFunction

      document.getElementById("myDIV").appendChild(para);

    }
      function f(){}
      </script>

      </div>
      <center>
      <button class="1" id="button" onClick="button();">Start</button></center>
```

I expect the output of this to be the previous span class to be disabled (onclick set to f())

Comment: firstly, you should use the html/css/js snippet of StackOverflow for us to be able to copy & modify your code easily (btw the html syntax is not correct, you should use `<head>` and `<body>` tags). secondly, so what you are trying to do is to spawn a `<span onclick="functionA">` and once it is clicked turn it into `<span onclick="functionB">` ?

Comment: @robinvrd yessir! Can you link me to how to properly do that?

Comment: it is just a button in the text editor of Stackoverflow right next to the Image buttons.

Comment: On first run, this will fail. There is never an element with an ID of  `a-1`. You're better off using a single variable (i.e, use just T instead of Q and T) and use `a + (t - 1)` to reference the previous span `if t > 0`.

Comment: @Lewis can you put it in an answer space?

Comment: I’m pretty sure that alone won’t fix your problem. Let me know if it does and I’ll post it as an answer, otherwise better off waiting to see if anyone else has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should define as much of the style of your elements as possible in CSS instead of defining it in Javascript.

Secondly, when a `onclick` is called in JS, the first parameter of the function should be `event` which is a representation of the click event that just appeared. Here in the `onclick` you can get the clicked element with `event.toElement` which allows you to redefine `onclick`.

I think what you are trying to do should look like something like this :

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
}

function spawn() {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");  
  span.style.left = getRndInteger(30, (container.offsetWidth - 30)) + "px";
  span.style.top = getRndInteger(30, (container.offsetHeight - 30)) + "px";
  
  span.onclick = fA;
  
  container.appendChild(span);
}

function fA(event) {
  var span = event.toElement
  alert("first click here");
  span.onclick = fB;
}

function fB(event) {
  alert("second click here");
}
```

```css
div#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

div#container span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  
  position: absolute;
  
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="spawn()">Spawn a span</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```